# Wave equation governing ideal waves

Tags: waves

I have a question about what $w$ means in the wave equation $A$$cos$($kx-wt$). From what I've understood, in classical physics, angular velocity has to be taken about a point or about an axis about which something spins around, so I'm not clear as to what angular velocity means in terms of a wave. Is it how many radians per second any one point on the wave is rotating with respect to the origin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the significance of angular frequency $\omega$ with regards to wave functions?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/176193/)

Answer (score 1):

In general, omega or angular velocity is ho many radians per second some sort of point that is rotating covers. But as you know, rotation is a kind of motion where a point repeats its path after some time, called T or period. Number of times that a point does this in one second is called frequency. Angular frequency tells you how much of its orbit which is circular a point passes in radians in one second. So if it is two pie radians in omega, it is exactly ONE in frequency, or 1 Hz. Imagine now that a point does not rotate but still moves in such a way to repeat its motion after some period T, like a medium particle in  medium through which there exists some wave motion. So this particle might not be doing circular orbits but it still has a frequency (number of cycles per second) and still has a period.So it needs only a angular frequency right? So why not give it one and than describe its motion using sine or cosine? Maybe its motion is such that when it moves up and down it acts like one coordinate of a point moving in a circle so when a point moving in a circle finishes its one circle so does its coordinate.Now we do not have a point moving in a circle but that does not mean we can not imagine there is one and assign to it some omega or angular frequency. In doing so we allow ourselves to describe some oscilatory motion by using sine or cosine. So in this way, our angular frequeny describes how much of a total cycle a point finishes in one second and this cycle does not have to be circulatory motion it can be any kind of oscilatory motion. So now, if I say it has 4pie rad/s it means two complete cycles in one sec or two hertz...Some people imagine this motion up and down as being projection of a stick that moves arround in a circle but we only see its shadow on some wall. So the shadow actually has the same frequency, so why not assign to it also the same angular frequency? Of course, this motion has to be regular and not any type of such motion can be described in this way, it has to be so called harmonic oscilatory motion.